# docker run hello-world still fails, permission denied

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I'm trying to run docker but it still fails. Here is what i get

```
root@c1170137:~# docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

c04b14da8d14: Extracting    974 B/974 B
docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

kernel: 4.4.16-1-pve

i'm using debian jessie

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:        8.5
Codename:       jessie
```

Edit:
daemon.log
http://hastebin.com/qinufacuto.coffee

docker info

```
root@c1177124:~# docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 4.4.16-1-pve
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 32
Total Memory: 2 GiB
Name: c1177124
ID: 4YUJ:OL2E:WLJC:23WJ:5HRW:LRY3:QHKC:MKXO:JDWO:VWOQ:JMWN:V52W
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

By the way, the problem could be caused by the kernel.
Thank you for any idea or solution

Comment: Can you run the command with `docker -D` debug flag on and paste the output.

Comment: @nash_ag like this? `root@c1177124:~# docker -D run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
c04b14da8d14: Extracting    974 B/974 B
docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: Added the daemon.log to the post

Comment: Also add `docker info`

Comment: @Alkaline Yep, added

Comment: does it work if you use `sudo docker run hello-world` ?

Comment: sudo works never for me, so no

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 9):

Use `lxc.apparmor.profile: unconfined`

Just put at the end of an `/etc/pve/lxc/ID.conf` file and restart your LXC container.

Using `lxc.aa_profile: unconfined` is deprecated as was renamed.

Comment: What if I don't have /etc/pve/lxc/<ID>.conf file?

Comment: Useless comment: you saved my day <3

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about security or trust your docker containers:

1. Edit the configuration file of your lxc container on the host in `/etc/pve/lxc/ID.conf` by adding `lxc.aa_profile: unconfined` at the end of the file.
2. Remove apparmor: `apt-get remove apparmor --purge`

Comment: Worked perfectly for Proxmox was having issues with Proxmox overwriting specific lxc settings, using the specific Proxmox config fixed everything, thanks!

Comment: Deprecated. Use `lxc.apparmor.profile: unconfined` instead. Just put at the end of an ID.conf file and restart your LXC container.

Comment: Removing apparmor is like taking the doors off your car all together because you had to put your coffee down one day so you could get a free hand to open it with. @AndreyVolk , can you place this in its own answer so I can properly vote for it?

Comment: when you stuck removed apparmor please follow install instruction https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_Stretch and apt-installl proxmox-ve

Answer (score 1):

Iam Solved this problem with execute this command on **Host**:

lxc config set your-lxc-name security.nesting true

lxc config set your-lxc-name security.privileged true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case it was due to McAfee antivirus. I removed it and then pull successfully. McAffe was blocking the /etc/passwd folder and Docker could not pull images.

Here people had the same exact problem:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37817